# Scanning a barcode with an ASCII control character into an input field

Tags: javascript, html, ascii, barcode

I need to scan a barcode with [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) 29 (group separator) into an HTML input field, and replace all the group separators with |. The following JavaScript function works when I first scan the barcode into [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) and then copy it to the input field, but not when the barcode is scanned directly into the input field. What's the problem?

```
var barcode = document.getElementById('barcode').value;
barcode = barcode.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(29), 'g'), '|');
alert(barcode);
```

Comment: Probably a browser limitation. Which browsers have you tested?

Comment: Can you use the browser dev tools to inspect the value of the data being put into the html input field after you scan a bar code and verify that it has ASCII 29 values in it?

Comment: I'm guessing that the browser is stripping out control codes in that input field.

Answer (score 1):

On my Symbol Tech barcode scanner, characters are sent as key strokes. For example, the group separator will emulate holding down the left_control key and then sending a right bracket. Your browser will handle the simulated key strokes as if you were trying to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> as a shortcut.

You can capture this event with **onkeydown** and event.which as described here:
[Firefox onkeydown detect pressed key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642040/firefox-onkeydown-detect-pressed-key)