# ASP.NET - onkeydown event not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, onkeydown

So I am having an issue in Firefox with the onkeydown event for an image button.  I don't want the button action to fire until they let up off the button.  So this works great in both IE and Chrome.  I cannot figure out why it doesn't work in Firefox(20.0.1).  Here is the image button code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnButton1" ImageUrl="/images/target.png" runat="server" 
Height="75" Width="75" onkeydown="return false;" onkeyup="ButtonClick()" />
```

So the onkeyup seems to work perfect in all browsers, but the onkeydown does not want to work in Firefox and I cannot figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't know if it will help, but I will post my JavaScript function for onkeyup as well:

```
 function ButtonClick() {
    document.getElementById('<%=btnButton1.ClientID %>').click();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Theres another topic covering this issue with firefox! take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642040/firefox-onkeydown-detect-pressed-key! hopes its help you

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, you can try?

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".chat-input ", function (val) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      //codes
    }, 1);
}).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('.chat-input').trigger('keypress');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

please try using

```
function ButtonClick() {
    document.getElementById('<%#btnButton1.ClientID %>').click();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but that part of my code is functioning perfectly on all browsers.  the problem is the onkeyup="return false;" does not want to work on Firefox. Works in Chrome and IE. So in Firefox they can hold the button down, and it also counts 2 clicks for each click.