# Changing div color with key presses in HTML/JS/JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

Basically what I want to be able to do is change a single div's color depending on a key press. ex. If I press "w" the background color will turn green "s" will turn it red etc.

I didn't post any link to my code because basically I just have a 50px by 50px div and I don't really know where to go. Maybe this is really easy but all I know for coding is from the Codeacademy lessons on HTML/CSS. Thanks in advance for anything you can show me or point me to.

Comment: So whenever the user presses a key while on your page, or when their mouse is over the div or something?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a slightly more extensible approach:

```
// creating a map of the relation between the keyboard character pressed
// and the colour it should generate; 'color.b' and 'color["b"]' both give
// 'blue' for example:
var colorMap = {
    'b' : 'blue',
    'r' : 'red',
    'w' : 'white',
    'f' : 'fuchsia'
};

// binding the keypress event on the document:    
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    // creating a string from the character-code of the pressed key,
    // e.which returns the jQuery-normalised character code,
    // converting that string to lower case:
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();

    // using the css() method to set the background-color to the
    // color returned from the colorMap[letter] call:
    $('#swatch').css('background-color', colorMap[letter]);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jA7Ck/).

Edited to add a fall-back (to prevent any unsanitary errors wending their way to the console, or whatever):

```
var colorMap = {
    'b' : 'blue',
    'r' : 'red',
    'w' : 'white',
    'f' : 'fuchsia'
};

$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
    // broadly the same as above, but using the anonymous function,
    // i is the index of the current element among the collection returned
    // by the selector;
    // currentColour is the current value of the property we're updating:
    $('#swatch').css('background-color', function(i,currentColour){
        // returns the colorMap[letter] colour or, if one doesn't exist,
        // returns the existing colour instead:
        return colorMap[letter] || currentColour;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jA7Ck/1/).

To use Plain JavaScript instead of the jQuery library:

```
// arguments are required,
// target is the element whose property we're changing,
// event is the event-object,
// propertyName is the name of the property we're changing:
function changeProperty (target, event, propertyName) {
    // if any of those are not supplied, we quit right here:
    if (!target || !event || !propertyName) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // if target is a node (and has a nodeType) *and* is an HTMLElement (
        // with a nodeType === 1) we use that, otherwise we assume it's a string
        // and use getElementById() to retrieve that element:
        target = target.nodeType && target.nodeType === 1 ? target : document.getElementById(target);

        // as above, but there's no normalisation of the event.which,
        // so we're relying on browsers to comply with standards:
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase(),

            // getting the old property-value, using window.getComputedStyle:
            oldPropertyValue = window.getComputedStyle(target,null)[propertyName];

        // setting the style property to the value returned by the colorMap, or
        // to the current value if no value is returned by the colorMap:
        target.style[propertyName] = colorMap[letter] || oldPropertyValue;
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    changeProperty(document.getElementById('swatch'), e, 'backgroundColor');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jA7Ck/3/).

The above written for the following HTML:

```
<div id="swatch"></div>
```

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
  - [`event.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.which).
  - [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType).
  - [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).
  - [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
  - [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: So, an interesting down vote; thoughts on why? Is there something wrong with this answer that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

That's not too difficult.

Basically, you have to listen to the keypress event. This event will give you a code corresponding to the key pressed.

[From Jquery's doc :](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    // enter pressed
  }
});
```

If you need to listen for several keys, you use more `if` :

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    // key 13 is pressed
  }
  else if (e.which == 14) {
    // key 14 is pressed
  }
});
```

If you want to know what are the key codes, this'll display the number in the console :

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
});
```

Finally, to change a color, use .css(), per exemple if your div has a `#mydiv` `id` :

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $("#mydiv").css("color", "red");
  }
  else if (e.which == 14) {
    $("#mydiv").css("color", "blue");
  }
});
```

There may be more elegants way to do this (assign the color to a var, put the css at the end), but that may be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Combining some logic for obtaining the key code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/642111/2461379) I mocked up something.  Basically you listen for a `KeyUp` event, check which key it is, and perform appropriate logic.

```
document.onkeyup = function() {
    var keyCode = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : event.which;
    changeColor(keyCode);
}

function changeColor(keyCode) {
    if (keyCode == 87 ) { // w
        document.getElementById.style.background = "red";
    } else if (keyCode == 83 ) { // s
        document.getElementById.style.background = "green";
    } else if (keyCode == someOtherKeyCode) {
        // Other color change
    }
}
```

You can reference the keycodes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

```
65 - a
66 - b
... etc ...
```

But a more reliable method of checking may just be to check it:

```
document.onkeyup = function (event) {
    var keyCode = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : event.which;
    alert(keyCode);
}
```

which you could just put into the console and test out keys.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FXqx/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r8SC6/

I have written only for 2 alphabets(W,K) you may repeat the procedure after identifying more keyCodes

uncomment the alert line in order to know more keyCodes, once uncommented every key press would first ALERT the keycode

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   //alert(e.keyCode);

    if(e.keyCode==75)
    {
     //alphabet K 
           $("#square").css("background","green");
    }

   if(e.keyCode==87)
   {
   //alphabet W 
        $("#square").css("background","red");
    }    

});


})
```